# Use a odd number in a condition SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In Sweden the second to last digit in the [personal identity number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_%28Sweden%29) is ODD if you are a MAN and EVEN if you are a WOMAN.

I want to make this query so that it only selects the women (even numbers).

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4 FROM TABLE
INNER JOIN TABLE.COL ON TABLE.COL = TABLE.COL
INNER JOIN TABLE.COL ON TABLE.COL = TABLE.COL
WHERE COL = 'TEXT'
AND COL > 5000
AND RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2) = %2 <> 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE CAST (LEFT(RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2),1) AS INT) % 2 = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

To pick even numbers, the remainder of the number divided by 2 must be 0, thus:

```
RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2) % 2 = 0
```

But `RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2)` doesn't return the second last digit, it instead returns the last 2 digits. Divide it by 10 to get what you want:

```
RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2)/10 % 2 = 0
```

Another way to get the 2 last digits would be finding the remaining of the number divided by 100, thus:

```
IDNUMBER % 100 / 10 % 2 = 0
```

Actually, we only need to divide by 10, as division by 2 is only dependent on the last digit of a number:

```
IDNUMBER / 10 % 2 = 0
```

Comment: IDNUMBER / 10 % 2 = 0` will actually correctly check just whatever second to last digit is even. +1 for simplest solution. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44547/1

Answer (score 3):

If the second digit from the right determines "Male" or "Female", then you should be doing this:

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4 FROM TABLE
INNER JOIN TABLE.COL ON TABLE.COL = TABLE.COL
INNER JOIN TABLE.COL ON TABLE.COL = TABLE.COL
WHERE COL = 'TEXT'
AND COL > 5000
AND LEFT(RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2),1)%2 = 0 --Female. <>0 will give you Male
```

Raj

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
LEFT(RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2),1) IN ('0', '2', '4', '6', '8')
```

or

```
LEFT(RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2),1) LIKE '[02468]'
```

or

```
RIGHT(IDNUMBER,2) LIKE '[02468]_'
```

or even:

```
IDNUMBER LIKE '%[02468]_'
```